# JPA 2: Exception using @Table annotation

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, annotations, jpa-2.0

when i try to using `@Table(" \" Employee \" ")` annotation , it generate the exception. there is following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '" Employee "  (name, salary) values ('Jimmy', 35000)' at line 1
```

without using escape character  the employee table generate successfully, but i want to generate table name "Employee" .

Comment: Just out of curiosity... why?

Comment: because when use the `@Table` annotation in this way , the table name in database is `employee` . but i want to formatting the table name in   database like `Employee` .

Comment: What database are you using? it may not support quotes in table names

Comment: why do you want to have 'Employee' instead of 'employee'? in most of database systems the name of the tables is case insensitive

Comment: i know , but its JPA 2.0 specification , i want to execute this , it is exceptional case , but some time want to formatting the table name. I prepare my self for OCE-JPA certification

Comment: Have you tried to write it without spaces?

Comment: without space it will run successfully , but the table name is still `employee` and i want `Employee` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate as an JPA implementation is not only technology in stack that affects how case sensitivity of database table names is handled. Capacities of database and how is set up do play crucial role.

In MySQL case sensitivity of table names is controlled via [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) system variable. For example in Windows default is lowercase names an case insensitive comparisons. Also if operating system does not have case sensitive file system, consequence is that table names cannot be stored case sensitively.

Comment: it means now , it is not possible for table name `Employee` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same, as I see the default is lowercase.